# Flatlist get value from item

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I want to get a value from the state based on the item that the flatlist is rendering like so `this.state.liked[item.apiName]` i don't know why it doesn't work.
FlatList:

```
  <FlatList
    refreshing={this.props.loading}
    onRefresh={this.props.refresh}
    data={this.props.series}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <Serie
        serie={item}
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
        handleLike={this._likeSerie}
        liked={this.state.liked[item.apiName]}
      />
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
```

Comment: Try changing liked to
liked={() => this.state.liked[item.apiName]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently addding the `extraData={this.state.liked}` prop fixed the issue

Comment: That's because `data` is for the initial data, and `extraData` is for anything added later. Before `FlatList`, you had to manually manage all of this inside `componentWillReceiveProps`